# ¿Cómo insertar en tabla de base de datos con condición?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

Trataré de explicar mejor el título.

En mi WebApp (asp.net Core 2.0) tengo una tabla donde ingreso el detalle de los planes de pagos (o financiación) que el cliente hace para cancelar una deuda que tiene. 
Cuando emito un recibo va cancelando la cuota correspondiente. 
Pongo un print de pantalla de como se en el View:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda para conseguir que cuando ingreso un recibo (siguiendo el ejemplo de la imagen) superior al monto de la cuota, cancele primero la cuota correspondiente y al saldo lo traslade a la siguiente cuota.

No tengo nada escrito porque no se por donde arrancar.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes empezar con el algoritmo de tu problema.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. Si bien tengo una idea de como es el procedimiento, no conozco las "herramientas" para llevarlo a cabo. Ten en cuenta que mis conocimientos son básicos y algo de teoría no la tengo clara. Las dudas que me surgen al pensar son: ¿Cómo le "digo" que una vez que el monto de la cuota quede saldado, pase a la otra cuota? ¿Se hace con `if`?. Seguire en el proceso. Muchas gracias por comentar.

Comment: if( recibo > montoCuota ){
    cancelarCuotaCorrespondiente();
    siguienteCuota();
}

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a un amigo puede realizarlo. 
Primero creo una variable del monto que se paga y hago una lista con las cuotas que quedan por cancelar del plan de pagos:

```
//convierto a decimal el monto total del pago del recibo
        decimal montototalrecibo = Convert.ToDecimal(Monto_pago);            
        var listafaltapagar = _context.DetallesPlanesPagos.Where(o => o.Dni == Convert.ToInt32(Dni) && o.Estado == "Activo" && o.Saldo_cuota != 0).ToList();
```

Seguido a eso recorro la lista de las cuotas pendientes y coloco un `if` para verificar si el pago es mayor al monto de la cuota o si es menor.

```
foreach(var item in listafaltapagar)
                        {
                            if(montototalrecibo > 0)
                            {
                                if(montototalrecibo >= item.Saldo_cuota)
                                {
                                    montototalrecibo = montototalrecibo - item.Saldo_cuota;
                                    item.Saldo_cuota = 0;

                                    _logger.LogInformation("Recibo creado por Usuario: {ID}.", User.Identity.Name);
                                    _context.Add(recibo);

                                    //agrego Id al recibo                                        
                                    recibo.DetallePlanPagosId = item.Id;

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    item.Saldo_cuota = item.Saldo_cuota - montototalrecibo;
                                    montototalrecibo = 0;

                                    _logger.LogInformation("Recibo creado por Usuario: {ID}.", User.Identity.Name);
                                    _context.Add(recibo);


                                    //agrego Id al recibo                                        
                                    recibo.DetallePlanPagosId = item.Id;
                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Luego guardo los cambios y finaliza el proceso.
Muchas gracias a todos!